# Recursively (?) compose LINQ predicates into a single predicate

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, recursion, functional-programming, composition

(EDIT: I have asked the wrong question. The *real* problem I'm having is over at [Compose LINQ-to-SQL predicates into a single predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782940/compose-linq-to-sql-predicates-into-a-single-predicate) - but this one got some good answers so I've left it up!)

Given the following search text:

```
"keyword1 keyword2 keyword3   ... keywordN"
```

I want to end up with the following SQL:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM Customer 
  WHERE 
    (Customer.Forenames LIKE '%keyword1%' OR Customer.Surname LIKE '%keyword1%')
  AND
     (Customer.Forenames LIKE '%keyword2%' OR Customer.Surname LIKE '%keyword2%')
  AND 
    (Customer.Forenames LIKE '%keyword3%' OR Customer.Surname LIKE '%keyword3%')
  AND
    ...
  AND 
    (Customer.Forenames LIKE '%keywordN%' OR Customer.Surname LIKE '%keywordN%')
```

Effectively, we're splitting the search text on spaces, trimming each token, constructing a multi-part OR clause based on each token, and then AND'ing the clauses together.

I'm doing this in Linq-to-SQL, and I have no idea how to dynamically compose a predicate based on an arbitrarily-long list of subpredicates. For a known number of clauses, it's easy to compose the predicates manually:

```
dataContext.Customers.Where(
    (Customer.Forenames.Contains("keyword1") || Customer.Surname.Contains("keyword1")
    &&
    (Customer.Forenames.Contains("keyword2") || Customer.Surname.Contains("keyword2")
    &&
    (Customer.Forenames.Contains("keyword3") || Customer.Surname.Contains("keyword3")
);
```

but I want to handle an arbitrary list of search terms. I got as far as

```
Func<Customer, bool> predicate = /* predicate */;
foreach(var token in tokens) {
    predicate = (customer 
        => predicate(customer) 
        && 
         (customer.Forenames.Contains(token) || customer.Surname.Contains(token));
}
```

That produces a StackOverflowException - presumably because the predicate() on the RHS of the assignment isn't actually evaluated until runtime, at which point it ends up calling itself... or something.

In short, I need a technique that, given two predicates, will return a single predicate composing the two source predicates with a supplied operator, but restricted to the operators explicitly supported by Linq-to-SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: @KennyTM - not sure I follow what you mean... can you elaborate (please) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest another technique

you can do:

```
var query = dataContext.Customers;
```

and then, inside a cycle do

```
foreach(string keyword in keywordlist)
{
    query = query.Where(Customer.Forenames.Contains(keyword) || Customer.Surname.Contains(keyword));
}
```

Comment: Of course... when you put it like that, it seems so simple :) Awesome. Thankyou.

Comment: D'oh. I asked the wrong question. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782940/compose-linq-to-sql-predicates-into-a-single-predicate for what I'm really trying to achieve. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more succinct and declarative way of writing this, you could also use `Aggregate` extension method instead of `foreach` loop and mutable variable:

```
var query = keywordlist.Aggregate(dataContext.Customers, (q, keyword) => 
    q.Where(Customer.Forenames.Contains(keyword) || 
            Customer.Surname.Contains(keyword));
```

This takes `dataContext.Customers` as the initial state and then updates this state (query) for every keyword in the list using the given aggregation function (which just calls `Where` as Gnomo suggests.